# Displaying File name varies among browsers in (input type=file)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly">
 <div class="file_input_div">
  <input id="fileInputButton" type="button" value="Browse" class="file_input_button" />
  <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" name="file"
      onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value" 
      onmouseover="document.getElementById('fileInputButton').className='file_input_button_hover';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('fileInputButton').className='file_input_button';" />
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

css

```
<style type="text/css">

.file_input_textbox {height:25px;width:200px;float:left; }
.file_input_div     {position: relative;width:80px;height:26px;overflow: hidden; }
.file_input_button  {width: 80px;position:absolute;top:0px;
                     border:1px solid #F0F0EE;padding:2px 8px 2px 8px; font-weight:bold; height:25px; margin:0px; margin-right:5px; }
.file_input_button_hover{width:80px;position:absolute;top:0px;
                     border:1px solid #0A246A; background-color:#B2BBD0;padding:2px 8px 2px 8px; height:25px; margin:0px; font-weight:bold; margin-right:5px; }
.file_input_hidden  {font-size:45px;position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;cursor:pointer;
                     opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);-ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=0)";-khtml-opacity:0;-moz-opacity:0; }
</style>
```

In chrome,When I uploaded the file,the filename in the textbox displays like "c:\fakepath\filename" this path. In mozilla, filename in the textbox displays like "filename". I need the output like in mozilla. I don't have any clue why in chrome it displays like full path? How to avoid that?

Comment: You can't. It's not within your reach as it is defined in the browser.

Comment: Actual Filepath is fine. But it displays like "c:\fakepath\" How to remove this line in the textbox

Comment: @VidhyaRaju You can hide original input[type="file"] and provide new simple markup. Use plugin like https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload , http://www.plupload.com or create own.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control this by any `HACK`

It depends on browser.

[**See what MICROSOFT says :**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535128(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The fully qualified filename of the selected file is returned only
>   when this setting is enabled. When the setting is disabled, Internet
>   Explorer 8 replaces the local drive and directory path with the string
>   C:\fakepath\ in order to prevent inappropriate information disclosure.
>   To illustrate, suppose you attempt to upload a file named
>   C:\users\contoso\documents\file.txt. When you do this, the value of
>   the value property is set to c:\fakepath\file.txt.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#File_inputs)

```
You can't set the value of a file picker from a script; doing something like the following has no effect:

var e = getElementById("someFileInputElement");
e.value = "foo";
```

This requirement is already implemented in Internet Explorer 8 – the real path to the file will be shown only if the page that contains the control is added to the trusted sites collection of the browser. - [davidwalsh](http://davidwalsh.name/fakepath)